# Rails: NameError in LineItemsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web

```
undefined local variable or method `line_items' for #<Cart:0x000000000ce78a18>

Extracted source (around line #3):
1 class Cart < ApplicationRecord
2 def add_product(product)
3   current_item = line_items.find_by(product_id: product.id)
4   if current_item
5     current_item.quantity += 1
6   else
              
app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:27:in `create'

25 def create
26    product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
27    @line_item = @cart.add_product(product)
28
29    respond_to do |format|
30      if @line_item.save
```

I was running an example from Agile Web Development with Rails 6
Sam Ruby, David Bryant Copeland with Dave Thomas, on page 134 (Chapter 10. Task E: A Smarter Cart • 134), and encountered this issue.
I was wondering whether anyone has run on the same issue and how was it resolved...? Any input would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Ruby (like most other languages) require you to define a variable before using it. Looking at the error trace, `add_product` tries to get the value of `line_items` on line 3, but it's not used prior. Hard to say without seeing the rest of the code, but I'd guess `line_items` is meant to be an instance variable, so you might need to use `@line_items` instead.

Comment: Just a guest by looking at the controller names. Check if you have to define a  `has_many` relation is required between Cart and LineItem models.

Something like 
  `has_many: line_items` in the cart.rb file

Answer (score 0):

I think @rmlockerd that `line_items` is meant to be an instance variable, or `line_items` could also be `LineItem` class

```
1 class Cart < ApplicationRecord
2 def add_product(product)
3   current_item = LineItem.find_by(product_id: product.id)
4   if current_item.present?
5     current_item.quantity += 1
6   else
```

Comment: Here is the complete code for rails6/depot/app/models/cart.rb as follows: class Cart < ApplicationRecord
def add_product(product)
 current_item = line_items.find_by(product_id: product.id)
 if current_item
  current_item.quantity += 1
 else
 current_item = line_items.build(product_id: product.id)
 end
 current_item
end
end